# insertUnorderedList bug in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am building WYSIWYG editor. Currently I am working on inserting unordered lists. I am using `document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList')`. Below is demo:

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList')">insert unordered list</button>
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p>First line</p><p>Secound line</p><p>Third line</p><p>Fourth line</p><p>Fifth line</p><p>Sixth line</p>
</div>
```

Everything here is working, but I've found bug. I don't know if you have that too (because when I tried this in IE, instead of Firefox, everything works), but make an experiment:

```
1. Select lines sixth, fifth and fourth (last three)
2. Click button
3. Select lines fifth, fourth and third
4. Click button
```

After that you should see one `<ul>` with four `<li>` but I see something strange: a second list (`<ul>`) appeared. Like on image:
[image]

I don't know how is it possible and how to repair it. If you know please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work in every browser (but I have tested it only in Firefox). Notice: This code uses JQuery.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList');
  
  //Remove empty lines
  $('ul > li > br').parent().remove();

 //Target new list
  var newList = $('ul:not(.ordered)');

  //If element after new list is previously created list, combine them in one list
  if (newList.next('ul:not(.ordered)').length > 0) {
    newList.append(newList.next().detach().contents().unwrap());
  }

  //If element before new list is previously created list, combine them in one list
  if (newList.prev('ul:not(.ordered)').length > 0) {
    newList.prepend(newList.prev().detach().contents().unwrap());
  }

  newList.addClass('ordered');
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>insert unordered list</button>
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  <p>First line</p>
  <p>Secound line</p>
  <p>Third line</p>
  <p>Fourth line</p>
  <p>Fifth line</p>
  <p>Sixth line</p>
</div>
```